# Visa question: How much do you earn from this job in a year?

Tags: standard-visitor-visas

I do not know how to answer this question. Ask me what I earn as salary in a year or what? Because I am the General Manager of my own company.

Comment: What do you declare to the government as your income for your personal tax returns?

Comment: It’s not a particularly difficult question - it just means ‘how much do you draw from the company as your personal income’. As @Moo says, the figure should equate to the amounts declared in your recent tax returns.

Answer (score 5):

> **How much do you earn from this job in a year?**

As you are the General Manager this means how much you pay yourself out of the company's money each year and take as your personal income or as mentioned by *Moo* in the comments:

> What do you declare to the government as your income for your personal tax returns?